# Access session information in tomcat custom JNDIRealm

Tags: authentication, tomcat9, realm-base-adapter

Im trying to write a custom JNDIRealm but how do I get access to the Request object?

The reason I doing so Is I have 2 LDAP servers one that does 2-Factor check. I need access to the Request object to see where the request is coming from. For Intranet users I using the plain LDAP server but for the internet users Im using the 2-Factor LDAP server

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it not possible... I had to update my login.jsp and access the Request object there and passed the information I needed in the j_username

```
var isWebProxyRequest = "<%= request.getHeader("PROXY_HEADER") != null ? "Y" : "N" %>";                                                  
getElement("j_username").value = (isWebProxyRequest == "Y" ? "WEB::" : "INTERNAL::") + getElement("username").value;
```

in my case I have a apache proxy that does my DDOS and other protections between the WEB and the TOMCAT that sets a header attribute. This is done by setting below in apache ssl.conf

```
RequestHeader set PROXY_HEADER xxxx
```

which I detect and set a variable say called TYPE to either WEB or INTRANET as shown above

I pass the TYPE to the j_username so when j_username is passed to Realm sees ::

Then I wrote my own custom realm called SelectorRealm as follows

```
package xxxx;

public class SelectionRealm extends CombinedRealm {
   private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SelectionRealm.class);

   public boolean checkSelector(Realm realm, String selector) {
      return ((SelectorRealm) realm).getSelector().equals(selector);
   }

   public String getUserName(String username) {
      return username.replaceAll("^.*::", "");
   }

   public String getSelector(String username) {
      return username.replaceAll("::.*$", "");
   }

   public Principal authenticate(String _username, String clientDigest, String nonce, String nc, String cnonce, String qop, String realmName, String md5a2) {
      Principal authenticatedUser = null;

      String username = getUserName(_username);
      String selector = getSelector(_username);
      log.info("username=" + username + " selector=" + selector);
      for (Realm realm : realms) {
         if (!checkSelector(realm, selector)) continue;

         authenticatedUser = realm.authenticate(username, clientDigest, nonce, nc, cnonce, qop, realmName, md5a2);
         break;
      }

      return authenticatedUser;
   }

   public Principal authenticate(String _username) {
      Principal authenticatedUser = null;

      String username = getUserName(_username);
      String selector = getSelector(_username);
      log.info("SelectionRealm: username=" + username + " selector=" + selector);
      for (Realm realm : realms) {
         if (!checkSelector(realm, selector)) continue;

         authenticatedUser = realm.authenticate(username);
         break;
      }
      return authenticatedUser;
   }

   public Principal authenticate(String _username, String credentials) {
      Principal authenticatedUser = null;

      String username = getUserName(_username);
      String selector = getSelector(_username);
      log.info("SelectionRealm: username=" + username + " selector=" + selector);
      for (Realm realm : realms) {
         if (!checkSelector(realm, selector)) continue;

         authenticatedUser = realm.authenticate(username, credentials);
         break;
      }

      return authenticatedUser;
   }

   public Principal authenticate(GSSContext gssContext, boolean storeCred) {
      UnsupportedOperationException uoe = new UnsupportedOperationException("SelectionRealm.authenticate.GSSContext");
      log.error("SelectionRealm.unexpectedMethod", uoe);
      throw uoe;
   }

   public Principal authenticate(GSSName gssName, GSSCredential gssCredential) {
      UnsupportedOperationException uoe = new UnsupportedOperationException("SelectionRealm.authenticate.GSSName");
      log.error("SelectionRealm.unexpectedMethod", uoe);
      throw uoe;
   }
}
```

and SelectorRealm as

```
package xxxx;

public interface SelectorRealm {
   public void setSelector(String selector);
   public String getSelector();
}
```

and custom JNDIRealm that implements SelectorRealm

```
package xxxx;

public class JNDIRealm extends org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm implements SelectorRealm {
   protected String selector = null;

   public void setSelector(String selector) {
      this.selector = selector;
   }

   public String getSelector() {
      return this.selector;
   }
}
```

so now my tomcat context.xml is set to

```
   <Realm className="xxxx.SelectionRealm" >
      <Realm className="xxxx.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
                       connectionURL="ldaps://${LDAP_INTERNAL_SERVER}:${LDAP_INTERNAL_PORT}"
             selector="INTERNAL"
             ... />

      <Realm className="xxxx.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
             connectionURL="ldaps://${LDAP_WEB_SERVER}:${LDAP_WEB_PORT}"
             selector="WEB"
             ... />
   </Realm>
```